# Tag merge / synonym request: [cache] → [caching]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [cache](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cache) (27 questions) into [caching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching) (79), and make them synonyms.

Tag *cache* does not have wiki nor excerpt. Tag *caching* wiki excerpt is

> Questions regarding cache algorithms by applications and implementations of information caching by database engines and other information repository and presentation applications.